# How can I identify a single character at a time in a line of text

Tags: c#, encryption, streamwriter

So I've gotten all the code written but I can only figure out how to change the value of a predetermined character, in this case e, where I need the value to change with the current character as it loops through the text

Thanks in advance

```
static void Encrypt()
        {
            int asciiVal;
            string CurrentLine;
            StreamReader CurrentReadFile = new StreamReader("EncMe.txt");
            StreamWriter CurrentWriteFile = new StreamWriter("temp.txt");
            while (!CurrentReadFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                string EncLine = "";
                CurrentLine = CurrentReadFile.ReadLine();
                foreach (char e in CurrentLine)
                {
                    char CurrentChar = 'e';
                    asciiVal = (int)CurrentChar;
                    asciiVal = asciiVal + 1;
                    CurrentChar = (char)asciiVal;
                    EncLine = EncLine + CurrentChar;
                }
                CurrentWriteFile.WriteLine(EncLine);
            }
            CurrentWriteFile.Close();
            CurrentReadFile.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `char CurrentChar = 'e';` should be `char CurrentChar = e;`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you trying to implement a Caesar cipher in C#? Note, you're not using the `e` variable. Please [edit] your question to include the input, the output that you get and the output that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have worked with C#, but you should just be able to say: `asciiVal = (int)e;` In your foreach loop, you are defining `e` as a char type variable that represents an individual character in the string `CurrentLine`. If you wanted to use the `char CurrentChar` variable, then you can just rewrite the foreach to say: `foreach(char CurrentChar in CurrentLine)` and then you should omit the `char CurrentLine = 'e';` line.

This would leave you with the following for your foreach loop:

```
foreach (char CurrentChar in CurrentLine){
      asciiVal = (int)CurrentChar;
      asciiVal += 1; /* If you will only ever increment by 1, you can also
                        use "asciiVal++;" */
      EncLine += (char)asciiVal;
 }
```

**Note**: please excuse any spelling or grammar errors. I am writing this from my phone.